Citing a Film in Chicago Style Using Biblatex
I'm having trouble finding a way to cite films in Chicago style using biblatex. JabRef doesn't have a built-in @movie or @film format from what I can see, and when I try to write the bib file myself, the citation doesn't come out as I'd like. The code I have so far is
@Movie{Kurosawa1997,
    director = {Kurosawa, Kiyoshi},
    publisher = {The Criterion Collection},
    year = {1997},
    title = {Cure},
}

In proper Chicago style, the bibliographic citation should come out as

Kurosawa, Kiyoshi, dir. Cure. 1997; Japan: The Criterion Collection, 2022. Blu-Ray.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
Edit: Here's my TeX code with the relevant bits:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{film.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    ....
    \printbibliography

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Did you check the manual? There should be a @video entry type.

@JasperHabicht I have taken a look at the documentation. From what I can tell, it says that @video uses the bibliography driver for @misc, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Relevant related Answer. Relevant specification.
